# PayPal: Tracking a User Through IPN From Adaptive Payments API

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-adaptive-payments

I need to track user payments on my site, but there is nothing in an IPN that I have been able to link to my original payment.

Some people suggested using the "custom" field (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251109/paypal-button-sending-custom-variable-through-ipn), but that doesn't seem to be an option through the Adaptive Payments API.

So are there any fields I can attach to my Pay API call or my SetPaymentOptions API call that will a) be invisible to the user, and b) come back in the IPN so I can track the payment?

My only other options are to either track with the paykey (but that seems wrong since it is public and expires and a given transaction can have several paykeys), or to send the ipn notification to a tracked url such as www.example.com/payments/ipn/{transaction_id}

I'm just fairly shocked if there's no legitimate way for me to track a payment.

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same problem - what is your solution? As I said, the link provided by @joscas is not working anymore...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this could be of use to you:
https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/forums/mobile/how-fetch-invoice-data-using-adaptive-payments-api

Comment: Hi, unfortunately the link is not working anymore! Can someone reproduce the stuff which can be found there?